# Pascal: Reading input number by number

Tags: arrays, integer, permutation, pascal

Simple question, but oddly enough I haven't been able to find any simple solution yet:
I want to store an input "1234" (without the quotation marks) to an array so that each number stores to a separate position as an integer (i.e. array[1] will be equal to 1 etc).

Btw (it might be of some help, or maybe suggestion for a different solution), I'm working on some simple permutation operations (lexicographic ordering, etc.) so I want to operate with the numbers individually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Var
s           :String;
myArray : Array[1..20] of Boolean;
code    :integer
Begin
s := "1234";
For i := 1 to length(s) do
 Begin
  Val(s[i], myArray[i], code);
 End;
End.
```

Comment: Surely the array is of integer? Otherwise thanks, this really does look like the simplest solution.